# JSON parse error on line 5 Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']'

Tags: json

Please some help. i have an error in line 5 and i could not find it.

---

```
{
    "_id": "_design/admin",
    "_rev": "23-99ab8890e8854137647859b56590a68c",
    "shows": {
        " les roles ": "function(doc,req) { return { body : [ "<h1>Le", doc._id, "de" ,     doc.role, "</h1>"].join("");};}"
    }
}
```

Comment: try `"les roles" : "function(doc,req) { return { body : [ \"<h1>Le\", doc._id, \"de\" ,     doc.role, \"</h1>\"].join(\"\");};}"`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error.

Comment: @Microtechie: the problem has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: @FelixKling  It was just a suggession as  JSON an acronym for JavaScript Object Notation

Comment: @Microtechie: Yes, but the name and the syntax is all they have in common. JSON is a language independent data-exchange format, like XML or CSV.

Answer (score 2):

You should escape quotes inside quotes like `\"`

Answer (score 1):

In "les roles" you have a string, which contains " (quote). For parser string ends there, and what is after the quote (Le) is unexpected for it.

Answer (score 0):

Escape double quotes in the string:

```
{
    "_id": "_design/admin",
    "_rev": "23-99ab8890e8854137647859b56590a68c",
    "shows": {
        " les roles ": "function(doc,req) { return { body : [ \"<h1>Le\", doc._id, \"de\" ,     doc.role, \"</h1>\"].join(\"\");};}"
    }
}
```

Or you can just use single quotes.